# Append Text to a dynamically generated Div via jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating `div` elements on click of a `button`. The div which are generated , are `draggable` and `resizable` .

On clicking the same dynamically generated div, a text box should appear where-in I put some text and then the same text should be appended **inside** that div.

But somehow the click event on the div is not registered. Any ideas?

jQuery:

```
$(".square").click(function () {
    alert("square clicked");
    $(".box").append("<div class='comp1'></div>");
    $(".box .comp1").resizable({
        containment: ".box"
    });
    $(".box .comp1").draggable({
        containment: ".box"
    });
});

$(".circle").click(function () {
    $(".box").append("<div class='comp2'></div>");
    $(".box .comp2").resizable({
        containment: ".box"
    });
    $(".box .comp2").draggable({
        containment: ".box"
    });
});

//script to append text
$(".comp1").click(function () {
    var obj = $(this);
    alert(1);

    $(".btnSaveTitle").click(function () {
        alert("save title clicked");
        alert($(".componentTitle").val());
        var title1 = $(".componentTitle").val();
        obj.append(title1);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success square">Table</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary circle">Round Table</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary square">Stage</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right btnSaveTitle">Save</button>
<input type="text" class="componentTitle pull-right" placeholder="name your component" />
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="box" style="border: double; height: 500px; position:relative ; width: 100%"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oauqs8ee/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use event delegation for newly created elements.

Also, you shouldn't register the `click` event handler inside another `click` handler.

```
// declare obj variable outside of the click handler:
var obj;
// delegate click event:
$(document).on('click', ".comp1", function () {
    // point the obj variable to the clicked element
    obj = $(this);
    alert(1);
});

// move click handler outside:
$(".btnSaveTitle").click(function () {
    // check whether the obj variable isn't undefined:
    if(obj !== undefined){
        alert("save title clicked");
        alert($(".componentTitle").val());
        var title1 = $(".componentTitle").val();
        obj.append(title1);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oauqs8ee/2/)

Comment: The fiddle is not working .. Also the alert `alert("save title clicked");` is not working.. Which means the click event is not triggering

Comment: The click does triggering. I have just commented out the alerts in Fiddle (I don't like alerts, as they take to long time and stop script from running. Use console for debugging instead). http://jsfiddle.net/02esepw9/